# Understanding bootstrap's grid breakpoints

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

So I have this row that looks like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6"></div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6"></div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6"></div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6"></div>
</div>
```

So to understand this it is basically saying, on large screens it will have 4 columns.

But for some screens I don't get it, it says 6 so that is 2 columns.  But it also goes down to a single column when you shrink the screen.

I would have though you have to declare it as:

```
col-sm-12
```

So that would make it a single column on the smallest viewport, and then define col-med-6 to make it 2 columns.

For some reason I am not 100% clear when trying to write my own grid layout.

What am I missing?

Comment: if you shrink the screen to be even narrower than the `col-sm-*` breakpoints the display will go to one column because you're not telling it to do anything when the viewport is smaller than `sm`. If you need control beyond the `sm` break points, you should also define the `col-xs-*` breakpoints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Basics

First of all it depends on the bootstrap version you are using. In the following i will talk about the current version bootstrap v4.1.3.

Think about your page divided in `12 columns`. As you already said `on large screens it will have 4 columns`. That's correct because if you define columns with `col-lg-3` means nothing else than `use this class if i have a large screen or a even larger screen`.

To visualize it let's have a look at a corresponding media query:

```
// Large devices (desktops, 992px and up)
@media (min-width: 992px) { ... }
```

This means your page will use `col-lg-3` (4 columns) for every page `larger 992px`.

To override this you can use `col-xl-2` (6 columns). Have a look at the corresponding media query:

```
// Extra large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up)
@media (min-width: 1200px) { ... }
```

If you append both `col-lg-3` and `col-xl-2` to your elements your page will use 4 columns for screens `between 992px and 1199px` and 6 columns for screen `larger 1200px`.

## How to develop my application (Example)

**1)** Start with your smallest screen (mobile first). What you want to achieve are mostly each column (full width) below each column. To achieve this add `col-12` to your elements or define nothing (`col-12` is default).

**2)** This defined class will now used as long as a new `@media` query got active. For example if we only define `col-12 col-lg-3` (or only `col-lg-3)` it will use `col-12` (full width columns) for the whole page until we reach a screen width of `992px`.

**3)** Just try around. Following [the documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/) you will get an expert in days. For example you can also center cols or some stuff like this but start with the basics and try to build your own bootstrap page.

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/240943/) that you can take as a starting example:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3" style="background: #6502d8">
      <h1>
        Article 1
      </h1>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3" style="background: #02d865">
      <h1>
        Article 2
      </h1>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3" style="background: #d86502">
      <h1>
        Article 3
      </h1>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3" style="background: #0275d8">
      <h1>
        Article 4
      </h1>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

`< 768px` - one full width column - all elements below each other

`>= 768px && < 1200px` - two columns

`>= 1200px` - four columns

Good luck!

Comment: ```col-xl-2``` will be 6 columns not 5 right?  6x2 = 12